# Finding $g(x)$ given $g(x)= \displaystyle\int_0^1e^{x+t}g(t) dt +x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$g(x)= \displaystyle\int_0^1e^{x+t}g(t) dt +x $$

How do I find $g(x)$ from the above functional equation?

**Attempt(s):**

- $\dfrac{g(x)-x}{e^x}= \displaystyle\int_0^1 e^t g(t)dt$
- Differentiated  to get $g'(x)+x = g(x)+1$ and double differentiated to get $g''(x)+1 = g'(x)$
- Wrote g(-x) and added to get $g(x)+g(-x)$ to see if anything useful canbe extracted.
- Tried integration by parts.

Answer is:

> $g(x)= \left(\dfrac{2}{3-e^2}\right)e^x + x$

Comment: If you have gotten the differential equation, why not just solve that? It looks like a linear DE, should be rather easy to solve using Laplace Transforms.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal We haven't been taught differential equations and Laplace transform.

Comment: Perhaps I am being dense based on these posted answers, but from $\frac{g(x) - x}{e^{x}} = \int_{0}^{1}e^{t}g(t)\operatorname{dt}$. Doesn't this simply mean that the LHS must be constant for all $x$ and the form of $g(x)$ is clear from there?

Comment: Yes @JessicaK Your comment was the most helpful to me . Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to differentiate. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

The solution of the differential equation
$$y'+x=y+1$$ satisfied by $g$ is

$$x+\lambda e^x$$

with
$$\lambda=\int_0^1(x+\lambda e^x)e^xdx$$
$$=1+\frac{\lambda}{2}(e^2-1)$$

thus
$$g(x)=x+\frac{2e^x}{(3-e^2)}$$

Comment: @Abcd $\lambda=\frac{g(x)-x}{e^x}=\int_0^1e^xg(x)dx$ as you wrote.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A:=\displaystyle \int_0^1\,\exp(t)\,g(t)\,\text{d}t$.  Then, the problem statement says that
$$g(x)=A\,\exp(x)+x\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
A&=\int_0^1\,\exp(t)\,g(t)\,\text{d}t=\int_0^1\,\exp(t)\,\big(A\,\exp(t)+t\big)\,\text{d}t
\\
&=A\,\int_0^1\,\exp(2t)\,\text{d}t+\int_0^1\,t\,\exp(t)\,\text{d}t
\\
&=\frac{A}{2}\,\big(\exp(2t)\big)\Big|^{t=1}_{t=0}+\Biggl(\big(t\,\exp(t)\big)\Big|_{t=0}^{t=1}-\int_0^1\,\exp(t)\,\text{d}t\Biggr)
\\
&=\frac{A}{2}\,\left(\text{e}^2-1\right)+\Biggl(\text{e}-\big(\exp(t)\big)\Big|^{t=1}_{t=0}\Biggr)=\frac{A}{2}\,\left(\text{e}^2-1\right)+\big(\text{e}-(\text{e}-1)\big)
\\&=\frac{A}{2}\,\left(\text{e}^2-1\right)+1\,.
\end{align}$$
This shows that
$$A=-\frac{2}{\text{e}^2-3}\,,$$
whence
$$g(x)=-\frac{2\,\exp(x)}{\text{e}^2-3}+x\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,,$$
which coincides with the answer key.

Comment: As a remark, it is not true from the given condition that $$\frac{g(x)-x}{\exp(x)}=\int_0^1\,g(t)\,\text{d}t\,.$$  The correct version is $$\frac{g(x)-x}{\exp(x)}=\int_0^1\,\color{red}{\exp(t)}\,g(t)\,\text{d}t\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

You have came to the point where you got:

$$g'(x)-g(x)=1-x$$

This is a good news, you can solve differential equations of this form quite easily. Observing the LHS, you see that it's the (algebraic) sum of a derivative of the function, and the function itself, similar to the form obtained when you differentiate the multiplication of two functions. But how do you modify this equation to get such a result? The answer is **integrating factor**, which in this case is:

$$I.F = e^{\int{-1dx}}$$

$$I.F = e^{-x}$$

Multiply the IF on both sides of the equation:

$$e^{-x}g'(x) - e^{-x}g(x) = e^{-x}(1-x)$$

You can see this conveniently becomes

$$\frac{d}{dx}\{e^{-x}g(x)\} = e^{-x}(1-x)$$

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

For the differential equation 
$$g'(x)+x = g(x)+1$$
Rewrite it as
$$g'(x)-1 = g(x)-x$$
$$(g(x)-x)' = g(x)-x$$
$$\int \frac {d(g(x)-x)}{ g(x)-x}=\int dx=x+K$$
$$\ln |g(x)-x|=x+K \implies g(x)=Ke^x+x$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to differentiate.
$$\frac{g(x)-x}{e^x}=\displaystyle\int_0^1e^{t}g(t) dt =C$$
Because the defined integral isn't function of $x$.
$$g(x)=x+Ce^x$$

$C=\displaystyle\int_0^1e^{t}\left(t+Ce^t \right) dt = \frac{e^2-1}{2}C+1\quad$ gives $\quad C=\frac{2}{3-e^2}$
$$g(x)=x+\frac{2e^x}{3-e^2}$$